# Grub Rescue: invalid arch independent ELF magic. Previously I had ''no such partition'' and ''unknown filesystem''

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

It all started when I formated the partition where Ubuntu was installed. I wanted to get rid of it. After I restart my computer I got Grub Rescue: unknown filesystem. After playing a little bit and trying stuff, I got then Grub Rescue: no such partition. And now I installed again Ubuntu and I ended up with Grub Rescue: invalid arch independent ELF magic.

I am making the thread because I have been trying to fix my computers for 2 days now and I was not able to do so. I looked through a lot of threads on here and other places.I've done my research but I just can't fix it.

I would appreciate help. Thank you.

PS: If I can't find any solution, I don't mind completely format my HDD. I need my computer this Wednesday I have work to do. But I don't know how to... lol :/

Comment: The duplicate question has directions on how to complete the removal of Ubuntu so you can boot it.